# OSX: Custom Command Line Commands Not Working on Mavericks

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to get Sublime Text 2 to work on command line. Since I upgraded to Mavericks I haven't had any luck.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/subl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  62 Mar 13 13:38 /usr/local/bin/subl -> /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl

$ subl htdocs/index.html
-bash: subl: command not found
```

Comment: What is the output of `type subl && ls -al $(type -P subl)`?

Comment: $ which subl - outputted nothing. --- $ type subl && ls -al $(type -P subl) OUTPUT: -bash: type: subl: not found

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al '/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'`?

Comment: File not found. It's supposed to be /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app. Silly typo on my part. It works now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: And all I had to do was ask questions. :)

Comment: If you're not looking for an answer anymore, consider deleting the question.